# How to open browser on windows with url which contains metacharacters

Tags: windows, perl, system, metacharacters

I tried to open browser with different ways
something like this

system('start ' . $url) or use special module Browser::Open
He opened url , but not all , only 
http://host.com/cgi-bin/nagios3/status.cgi?hostgroup=all

I forgot to notice , i need to open 
http://host.com/cgi-bin/nagios3/status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=detail&servicestatustypes=28&sorttype=2&sortoption=3

Comment: Windows `perl` or cygwin `perl`? (What's `perl -V:archname`)

Comment: MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` has special meaning for the shell, so you need to place the URL in quotes.

But `start` has a very unusual syntax. If the first argument is in quotes, it's taken to be the title of the Window. So you need to add a dummy first argument. The solution follows:

```
system(qq{start "" "$url"})
```

Comment: Yes  it's works in cmd , but in the perl script $url has to be interpolated , he's trying open the '$ulr' not the value.

Comment: Big thanks, very helpful, how could I forget about qq.

Comment: You could also use concatenation as you did originally.

Answer (score 0):

As per [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url ="http://host.com/cgi-bin/nagios3/status.cgi?hostgroup=all";
system('start', $url);
```

Screenshot for the code above running:

[image]

Comment: @DimaCandu are you sure? It works, screenshot added. Maybe you have to explain what is not working.

Comment: i need to open this url  http://host.com/cgi-bin/nagios3/status.cgi?hostgroup=all&style=detail&servicestatustypes=28&sorttype=2&sortoption=3